# Parallel website running to my original website

Tags: web-services, security, web-applications, web

We have been working on a gaming website. Recently while making note of the major traffic sources I noticed a website that I found to be a carbon-copy of our website. It uses our logo,everything same as ours but a different domain name. It cannot be, that domain name is pointing to our domain name. This is because at several places links are like `ccwebsite/our-links`. That website even has links to some images as `ccwebsite/our-images`.

What has happened ? How could have they done that ? What can I do to stop this ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things they might have done to copy your site, including but not limited to:

- Using a tool to scrape a complete copy of your site and place it on their server
- Use their DNS name to point to your site
- Manually re-create your site as their own
- Respond to requests to their site by scraping yours real-time and returning that as the response
- etc.

  > What can I do to stop this?

Not a whole lot.  You can try to prevent direct linking to your content by requiring referrer headers for your images and other resources so that requests need to come from pages you serve, but 1) those can be faked and 2) not all browsers will send those so you'd break a small percentage of legitimate users.  This also won't stop anybody from *copying* content, just from "deep linking" to it.

Ultimately, by having a website you are exposing that information to the internet.  On a technical level anybody can get that information.  If some information should be private you can secure that information behind a login or other authorization measures.  But if the information is publicly available then anybody can copy it.

"Stopping this" is more of a legal/jurisdictional/interpersonal concern than a technical one I'm afraid.  And Stack Overflow isn't in a position to offer that sort of advice.

Comment: `You can require referrer headers for your images and other resources so that requests need to come from pages you serve, but 1) those can be faked and 2) not all browsers will send those so you'd break a small percentage of legitimate users.` Can you please elaborate

Comment: @saplingPro: That's often a setting at the web server level.  For example, a quick Google search shows how to deny visitors by referrer using .htaccess in Apache: http://www.htaccess-guide.com/deny-visitors-by-referrer/  Note that this won't stop anybody from *copying* content, just from linking directly to it from their site.

Answer (score 0):

You could run your site with some lightweight authentication.  Just issue a cookie passively when they pull a page, and require the cookie to get access to resources.  If a user visits your site and then the parallel site, they'll still be able to get in, but if a user only knows about the parallel site and has never visited the real site, they will just see a crap ton of broken links and images.  This could be enough to discourage your doppelganger from keeping his site up.

Another (similar but more complex) option is to implement a CSRF mitigation.  Even though this isn't a CSRF situation, the same mitigation will work.  Essentially you'd issue a cookie as described above, but in addition insert the cookie value in the URLs for everything and require them to match.  This requires a bit more work (you'll need a filter or module inserted into the pipeline) but will keep out everybody except your own users.